# Searching for projection in $L^2[0,1]$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, projection

Hello I find this problem on a list of problems from my university but I am stuck.

$\textbf{Problem:}$
Let $L^2[0,1]$ and set $p_j(t)=t^j$ sucht that $U=span(p_1(t),p_2(t), p_3(t))$. Let $f(t)=t^3-t$. Find $u\in U$ such that
$$\|f-u\|=\inf_{v\in U}\|f-v\|$$

My attempt was try to write $U$ as a span of a orthonormal basis through Gram-Schmidt algorithm (using $p_1(t),p_2(t), p_3(t)$) but the result was very messy.

In general I do not know how to start this kind of problems, any suggestion?

Comment: Isn't $f \in U$ as $f = p_3 - p_1$? Then $u:=f$ is the closest element.

Comment: Here $f=p_3-p_1\in U$, so $u=f$ will minimize $\|f-u\|$.

Comment: Yes, thank you but I am looking for general solution, I think if I want to solve similar problem with another $f(t)$ I have to do the following $$f(t)\approx\sum_{k=1}^3c_kv_k\quad\text{where}\quad c_k=\langle f,v_k\rangle=\int_a^b f(t)v_k(t)\,dt$$

Comment: You need to clarify your question. As it is currently stated, it is clear that $f$ lies in $U$ so the $\inf$ is zero.

Comment: Gram-Schmidt is a perfect start. If you don't even need to normalize the vectors, it shouldn't be that horrible..